# How to hide/unhide rows based on cell value, multiple times in 1 sheet

Tags: hide, rows

When the value in B16 is "0", I need to hide some other rows, and also un-hide them when the value is "1".

But, here's my issue:

Also, in the same sheet:
If the value in H4 is "0", I need to hide some rows. When the value is "1", I need to un-hide these rows.

The first part is working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With Sheets("Checklist")

If Range("b16").Value = 0 Then rows("17:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
If Range("b16").Value >= 1 Then rows("17:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End With
End Sub
```

And here's where I understand I suck at VB
In other words, the code below is clearly not working. Can you please provide a working alternative?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With Sheets("Checklist")

Select Case Taget.Address

Case "$b$16"
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 0 Then         
rows("17:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If     

Case "$b$16"
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 0 Then         
rows("17:21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If     

Case "$h$4"
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 1 Then         
rows("23:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If     

Case "$h$4"
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 1 Then         
rows("23:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If     

End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks.